# Reliable HTTP/HTTPS Messaging/Notification Product

Tags: asynchronous, notifications, queue, messaging

I am looking for a product to solve a particular task and I'm having a hard time sorting out which product or type of product can accomplish the task.  I am looking for something to handle POSTing notifications via HTTPS.

One of my use cases is a mechanical turk type scenario.  A client will request a task be started via an API call.  A human will get this request do the task, tell the system the task is complete, and the system will send a HTTPS POST to a subscriber.  So it's a long-running async request.

I am looking for something that will take care of making this POST for me.  I would like something that is reliable and durable.  Of course I can write the POST myself, but all of the other niceties that come with a queuing application would be nice to have (and I don't wish to implement all that myself).

I have been looking at a number of queuing, MOM, and ESB products.  From what I can tell the queuing products don't seem to push notify over HTTPS and the MOM and ESB are a little too heavy handed I think.  For example I think BizTalk will do what I need but that has a lot of overhead.  The one solution I did find was Amazon's Simple Notification Service, but that appears to only send from the amazon.com domain, but I want the messages to be sent from my domain.

Can anyone help identify a product that will help?  Maybe I'm just overlooking something, not sure what I am looking for, or have to choose a different way of implementing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I was looking for was webhooks.  [Here's a great presentation on what they are and how they can be utilized.](http://www.slideshare.net/progrium/web-hooks-google-tech-talk)

Answer (score 0):

if you want a serverless way to do webhooks, check out IronWorker's webhook support, here's an article on it:  http://blog.iron.io/2012/04/one-webhook-to-rule-them-all-one-url.html

Answer (score 0):

nginx has a [messaging module](http://pushmodule.slact.net/) that may be just what you need.